# ASP.NET Core MemoryCache - Update item while being used

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, memorycache

I can't find any info on how exactly I should update the existing cache items.
Do I need to Lock the item before I update it?

What happens if users are iterating over the `ListOFStuff` cache item and some other task Sets it with new value during the read, what will happen?

```
cache.Set(“LS”, ListOFStuff);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://MemoryCa%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) MemoryCache is Thread safe, so don't have to implement Thread Safety by your own.